# Draw a line connecting two clicked div columns

Tags: jquery, css

I want a functionality to be implemented where i can connect 2 divs with a line on click event. The concept is about matching contents in 2 different columns same as match the following. Please help me as i have tried everything I could as I don't want to use any external or HTML5 canvas. Is it possible to achieve with jquery, css and html only. Please reply.Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to match some column A with some following column B when the user clicks on A? And what is the matching you're talking about? The question is not clear.

Comment: Suppose There are 2 columns A and B with 4 rows each. Now suppose user clicks a row in column A and then clicks a row in column B i want to draw or display a line between both the above mentioned rows. Similarly for each row

Comment: OK, what did you try already?

Comment: I'll add my code folder for you to check...it gives me insertAdjectHTML null exception...Thank you

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948513/updating-line-between-divs-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

I might have a potential idea for a line consisting of three lines - horizontal (from element), vertical (up or down) and horizontal (to another element) again. You could create 2 very small columns with rows between the column A and B without borders, then using jquery .css add coresponding borders to the right columns and rows.

If you wish for animating the lines, you could create divs that have a size of 0 initialy, then animate the size of the columns so the borders appear.

Here's a basic fidde: http://jsfiddle.net/3xPpc/
HTML:

```
  <div class="big-col">
    <div class="big-row blue"></div>
    <div class="big-row green"></div>
    <div class="big-row blue"></div>
    <div class="big-row green"></div>
</div>
<div class="small-col">
    <div id="row-1-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-2-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-3-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-4-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-5-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-6-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-7-left" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-8-left" class="small-row"></div>
</div>
<div class="small-col">
    <div id="row-1-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-2-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-3-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-4-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-5-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-6-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-7-right" class="small-row"></div>
    <div id="row-8-right" class="small-row"></div>
</div>
<div class="big-col">
    <div class="big-row blue"></div>
    <div class="big-row green"></div>
    <div class="big-row blue"></div>
    <div class="big-row green"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:
    .big-col {
    float: left;
    }

```
.small-col {
float: left;
}

.big-row {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;     
}

.blue {
background-color: blue;
}

.green {
background-color: green;
}

.small-row {
width: 40px;
height: 50px;     
}

#row-1-left {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

#row-5-right {
border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

#row-2-right, #row-3-right, #row-4-right, #row-5-right {
border-left: 1px solid orange;
}
```

All you have to do is to add the borders on click with jQuery.

Comment: Thank you all for your reposnse...it is resolved now..thank you very much

Comment: If any of the answers here was what you were looking for, please accept the relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Here's a piece of example of what you can do about this. Of course it can be much more flexible and elegant by some work. Right now it's connecting the `divs` on same row / column. The basic is checking the `top` / `left` positions of clicked elements and append some additional `divs` to draw lines. For the `divs` on same row i.e.

```
if (pos_1.top == pos_2.top) {
  // same row
  if (Math.abs(pos_1.left - pos_2.left) == 100) {
    // adjacent
      var bar = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top - 2 + div_1.height() / 2) + "px", "height" : "5px", "width" : "50px", "left" : ((pos_1.left > pos_2.left ? pos_2.left : pos_1.left) + 50) + "px" });
      $("body").append(bar);          
  } else {
    // same row not adjacent
      var bar1 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top + 50) + "px", "height" : "20px", "width" : "5px",  "left" : (pos_1.left - 2 + div_1.width() / 2) + "px"});
      var bar2 = bar1.clone().css({"left" : (pos_2.left - 2 + div_2.width() / 2) + "px"});
      var bar3 = $("<div></div>").addClass("connectbar").css({ "top" : (pos_1.top + 65) + "px", "left" : ((pos_1.left > pos_2.left ? pos_2.left : pos_1.left) + 25) + "px", "width" : "200px", "height" : "5px" });
      $("body").append(bar1).append(bar2).append(bar3);
  }
}
```

**[HERE'S THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y6ZuS/1/)**